# Testing Authorize.net ARB (SOAP) Create Subscription process.

Tags: asp.net, soap, authorize.net, authorize.net-arb

I am trying to integrate Authorize.net ARB Payment module into my asp.net application (using SOAP) , and for the same I need to  test the functions in it.
But for the **CreateSubscription()** method I get an error:
**The payment gateway account is in Test Mode. The request cannot be processed.**

So please tell me(if possible) how can I test the functions for ARB in TEST-MODE in my ASP.Net Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test using a [developer account](https://developer.authorize.net/testaccount/) as you cannot set up subscriptions in your live account, even in test mode.